# How to commit only a specific folder Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I am new on linux, and i really like it so far. But i have a problem with mercurial.

I have a folder that has 5 subfolder, each of them with a project. So i'm working at a project (a subfolder) and i want to commit modifications only from that folder.

So in linux what i did was:

cd /var/www/project_foder/subfolder

hg status //it brings all the modifications(also from other projects)

hg commit -m "Message"

but it commit all the project modifications.

**How can i commit only from the selected folder modifications.**

Thanks in advance for your answers!.

PS: sorry for my poor english

Comment: Is not duplicate, that post has solution for other problem What i need is to commit files from a certain folder.

Comment: You can specify the name of a folder instead of the name of a file (mentioned in the answer).

Comment: Yeap. You are right. Thanks  **Wooble**

Answer (score 9):

You can specify the folder name as argument. You can also make `hg status` and `hg commit` apply to the current directory (and sub dirs) only by using a single dot as argument, e.g.:

```
cd /var/www/project_foder/subfolder
hg status .
hg commit -m "Message" .
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the method. I didn't think of. Best regards David Levesque

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied with it.